# Return a name of class which is a Pair<>

Tags: java, kotlin

```
Kotlin 1.2.30
```

I have the following interface that I am implementing in my delegate adapter;

```
interface ItemDelegate<H : RecyclerView.ViewHolder, I> {
    fun itemType(): Class<out I>
    fun createHolder(parent: ViewGroup): H
    fun bindView(holder: H, item: I)
}
```

I have to return the name of the class, but as its a `Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>` I am not sure how to return this:

```
override fun itemType(): Class<out Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>> {
    return Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>::class.java
}
```

And in my implementing AdapterDelegate I have the following:

```
class ApartmentDescriptionDelegate
    : ItemDelegate<ApartmentDescriptionViewHolder, Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>> {

    override fun itemType(): Class<out Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>> {
        return Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>::class.java
    }

    override fun createHolder(parent: ViewGroup): ApartmentDescriptionViewHolder {
        return ApartmentDescriptionViewHolder(parent)
    }

    override fun bindView(holder: ApartmentDescriptionViewHolder, item: Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>) {
        holder.apartmentOverviewDescription.text = item.second.description
    }

    class ApartmentDescriptionViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val apartmentOverviewDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description)
    }
}
```

I have tried doing the following:
return Pair::class.java

But I get an error saying:

```
Only class names are allowed on the left hand side of a class literal
```

Comment: If possible try to change your data from `Pair<*,*>` to a custom class, otherwise you're gonna have to do some dirty workarounds due to type erasure.

Comment: Hi, That is not possible unfortunately. What would be the best workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can cast it to make Kotlin happy, like this:

```
override fun itemType(): Class<out Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>> {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    return Pair::class.java as Class<Pair<String, ApartmentItems.ApartmentDescription>>
}
```